# How to open safari debugger for iOS simulator right from the moment of opening web page?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, safari

I know how to open developer tools from the moment I've launched a web page, it becomes visible in developer menu and I can click to it and inspect it, but there is some code which is being executed on a launch, which I cannot debug. How can I open safari debugger in such way, so I could see everything right from the web page launch?